# Propose new time in OS X iCal

Tags: macos, calendar.app

Is there a way to propose new event time with iCal? When receiving new invitation I can't see any option to purpose alternative scheduling (as well as trying dragging the event).

I'm using OS X Lion's iCal with Gmail.